# Combinations with repeated elements in Maple

Tags: maple, computer-algebra-systems

How does one output the combinations (with repeated elements) in Maple? I tried:

> with(combinat):
>
> choose([a, b, c], 2)
>
> $$[[a, b], [a, c], [b, c]]$$

These are all combinations without repeated elements. How does one get [a,a], [b,b] and [c,c] in the output list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `choose(n, m)` mentions:

> If m is given, then only combinations of size m are generated; otherwise, all combinations are generated, including the empty combination, that is, the power set is generated and converted to a sorted list. **Note that duplicates in the list n are taken into account.**

This suggests this algorithm takes duplicate values correctly into consideration, you just need to mention those duplicates in the list explicitly. So something like this works just fine:

```
> choose([a, a, b, b, c, c], 2)
[[a, a], [a, b], [a, c], [b, b], [b, c], [c, c]]
```

While it would be nice to have this supported as an additional parameter, you can just write such function by yourself. Such as for example:

```
choose_with_repetition := proc (n, m, k:=1) 
local duplicated := [seq(op(n), i = 1 .. k)]:
return combinat:-choose(duplicated, m): 
end proc:
```

This will return combinations of members of $n$ length $m$ (to use original notation) with maximal of $k$ repetitions, so

```
> choose_with_repetition([a, b, c], 2)
[[a, b], [a, c], [b, c]]

> choose_with_repetition([a, b, c], 2, 2)
[[a, a], [a, b], [a, c], [b, b], [b, c], [c, c]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: That kind of looped list augmentation is quadratic cost in memory, yet such generation using `seq` is linear cost. It doesn't matter much for this example, since the `combinat:-choose` cost will dominate. But it's not best to encourage methodology with unnecessary higher order computational complexity. I suggest `duplicated := [seq(op(n), i=1..k)];` instead.

Comment: @acer Sure, updated based on the suggestion. Note that this was just a quick and dirty solution, not in any way meant to be optimized. But definitely better to do so if people read this in future. Thanks.